# formatting string for an array

Tags: php, arrays, string

I have stuck with searching of ways how to prepare strings to parsing them into arrays.

```
Nissan Micra 1.2dm3 80KM 2015r. 103 000km 
Hyundai Tucson 2dm3 141KM 2005r. 199 000km 
Volkswagen Passat 2dm3 140KM 2014r. 138 000km 
Nissan Note 1.4dm3 88KM 2007r. 120 000km
```

it's look simple, split string by " " and it's done, but, there also might be some "Land Rover Range Rover" and other long names, also passed km also will be splitted, so idk what to do with that. parse string over cycles each time so my script will check are there any "two-word+ names" inside to work right with them or any another way exists for splitting those strings into arrays correctly?

Comment: can you show us the desired outcome? are the the strings such as `dm3`, `r.`, etc fixed?

Comment: looks like you could split on "space+number"

Comment: @YongQuan it should be like array('Nissan', 'Micra', '1.2', '80', '2015','103000') and etc

Comment: @IdontDownVote hm, you give me a guess how to pass this with strpos and substr, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a great question. Typically you're expected to show some effort to solve problems yourself. Please keep this in mind for next time. However, assuming the format of the text is consistent, this is pretty easily solved with a regular expression.

```
$text = "Nissan Micra 1.2dm3 80KM 2015r. 103 000km";
$result = preg_match("/(.*?) ([\d.]+dm3) (\d+KM) (\d+r.) ([\d ]+km)/", $text, $matches);
var_dump($matches);
```

Output:

```
array(6) {
  [0] =>
  string(41) "Nissan Micra 1.2dm3 80KM 2015r. 103 000km"
  [1] =>
  string(12) "Nissan Micra"
  [2] =>
  string(6) "1.2dm3"
  [3] =>
  string(4) "80KM"
  [4] =>
  string(6) "2015r."
  [5] =>
  string(9) "103 000km"
}
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/gY0HeK/1

If you don't need units like km or dm<sup>3</sup>, you can always place them outside the parentheses like `([\d.]+)dm3`, `([\d ]+)km`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

okay, i found a solution for my question.
 1. list of brands. cheking string by list and deleting it from string
 2. from the end passing params: passed km, hp and etc, deleting with preg_replace letters(i need only those numbers) and deleting them from string
3. there in string will left only model name, so i don't need a long list of all models for checking model with it

hope it will help somebody who also got stuck with question like my one